# Landing page using CMS page with different layout

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'd like to create a landing page directly inside Prestashop (1.7.6.7) using a new CMS page. To create a good landing page the structure of the page and its elements should be different from the rest of the website (i.e. removing menu, language selector and other elements). Is there a possibilty to create a custom layout **only for 1 CMS page**? Or is there some other workaround to make this? In this page of official PS docs there are some examples of how to create custom layouts for products or categories but edits are not working for pages.

P.S. I'd like to create the landing inside PS because in this way I shouldn't embed manually all files (i.e. css) to obtain the same style in titles, colors, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known [third party](https://addons.prestashop.com/it/personalizzazione-pagine/19835-advanced-cms-contentmaker-for-landing-pages.html) add-on to create custom advanced CMS pages, or if you want to do it youself you can create the pages in Prestashop CMS and develop a little module that , using the hook **displayHeader** , check the CMS page where you are and load a different css / js to modify the page according to its ID.